# Angular 6 - Matierial Radio Button & Material Input

Tags: angular, forms, angular-material

I'm working on something like

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tayp2o

What I'm trying to do is :

- if I click on an input, select the correponding radio button - It's
  working
- if I click on a radio, give the focus to the corresponding
  input

The second goal is not working.  The focus is well given but lost immediately.  But clicking on the test button is working.

How can I do ?

Comment: have you tried with `viewChild('name') name: ElementRef; and this.name.nativeElement.focus();`

Comment: No, but with that solution it requires to have 1 viewChild per input.  So if I have a form with 10 radios / inputs I will have 10 viewChild and I will have to test wich radio is checked to give the focus to the right input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Problem is that you're trying to set the focus to an element by clicking on an other element. But HTML is setting the focus to the clicked element by default.

To solve this issue you could use a timeout inside your 'radioFocus' function:

```
radioFocus(event: any) {
  setTimeout(() => { document.getElementsByName(event.srcElement.id).item(0).focus(); }, 100);
}
```

Comment: I modified the stackblitz code but ... it is not working. Well ... sometimes it's working but most of time not.  I don't understand.

Comment: for me its working like a charm. are you clicking anywhere else after clicking on a radiobutton?

Comment: otherwise you could set the timeout form 100ms to 300ms to make sure its still working for the slower systems. :)

Comment: Ok, it's also working for me.  On my machine it's working fine with 100ms, on stackblitz with 300ms !  Many thanks.